# Can the full set of II. Bianchi identities be derived from the symmetries of the action?

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, field-theory, variational-principle, noethers-theorem

In pseudo-Riemannian geometry we can derive the [II. Bianchi identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Symmetries_and_identities) by considering, e.g. the expression of the Riemann tensor in [Riemann normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates). They read
$$R_{\mu\nu\kappa\lambda;\gamma} + R_{\mu\nu\gamma\kappa;\lambda} + R_{\mu\nu\lambda\gamma;\kappa} = 0\,.$$
In essence, they are a part of the integrability relations that specify that the curvature corresponds to a Levi-Civita connection (i.e. that it is generated by "a potential", the Christoffel symbols, which themselves are generated by another "potential", the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$).

Now consider the [Einstein-Hilbert action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) (modulo factors, cosmological constant zero for simplicity)
$$S_{\rm EH} = \int R \sqrt{-g} \, \mathrm{d^4} x \,. $$
We can show that it is invariant wrt infinitesimal coordinate transforms $x^\mu + \xi^\mu(x^\mu)$ and, even more, that this is true before applying field equations. This is an infinite-dimensional Lie symmetry of the action, which implies by the [second Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_second_theorem) a set of "strong conservation laws" that in this case are the twice contracted II. Bianchi identities
$$(R^{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}R g^{\mu
\nu})_{;\mu} = 0 \,.$$
That is, a part of the II. Bianchi identities can be derived from the symmetries of the E.-H. action. However, is there a way to derive the full set of II. Bianchi identities in this manner? That is, is there a variational procedure that would allow me to derive a larger set of Bianchi-type identities based on the symmetries of the Einstein-Hilbert action (or similar)?

Comment: A simple d.o.f. counting argument suggests your infinitesimal transformations need to be parametrized by 4-valent tensors. I don't know whether such a construct exists mathematically, but it is unlikely to play any role in known physics

Comment: It seems to me that metric-affine theory of gravity should provide the answer, see e.g. [McCrea et al., 1990](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00672931).